JSON GET request for list contained in object API
I'm doing an Android project where I must extract the necessary data from an API where the API itself is formatted as an object and the data I need to access is inside a list contained in the object API.  Here is the API I'm using and the data I need is the list with "RelatedTopics" as the key.  I'm using postman to test how to access that list but I'm not sure what the right query for the GET request is. The URL for the API is http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=simpsons+characters&format=json
{
    "RelatedTopics":[
        {
            "FirstURL": "https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilan",
            "Icon": {
                "Height": "",
                "URL": "",
                "Width": ""
            },
            "Result": "<a href=\"https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilan\">Apu Nahasapeemapetilan</a><br>Apu Nahasapeemapetilan is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\".",
            "Text": "Apu Nahasapeemapetilan - Apu Nahasapeemapetilan is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\"."
        },
        {
            "FirstURL": "https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilon",
            "Icon": {
                "Height": "",
                "URL": "/i/99b04638.png",
                "Width": ""
            },
            "Result": "<a href=\"https://duckduckgo.com/Apu_Nahasapeemapetilon\">Apu Nahasapeemapetilon</a><br>Apu Nahasapeemapetilon is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\".",
            "Text": "Apu Nahasapeemapetilon - Apu Nahasapeemapetilon is a recurring character in the American animated television series The Simpsons. He is an Indian immigrant proprietor who runs the Kwik-E-Mart, a popular convenience store in Springfield, and is known for his catchphrase, \"Thank you, come again\"."
        },
    ]
}

I've tried using query params (?) but I don't know if that is the right approach as well as routes (/) to access the list but that did not seem to work either.  Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you in advance

I'm not sure that you can navigate through json using url. Maybe it would be better to try to get response from your get request and then parse that response and extract list.
